# How can i verify a interval in array with one function

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i verify how many numbers in a array is in or out a 10-20 interval (10 and 20 included) in one function? I tried but i just got it with two functions, one to verify if its out and one to verify if its in.

```
let array = [1,3,7,10,14,18,20,23,27]

function inInterval(e){
    if (e >= 10 && e <=20) {
        return e
    }
}

function outInterval(e) {
    if (e <10 || e>20) {
        return e
    }
}

let inIntervalResult = array.filter(inInterval).length
let outIntervalResult = array.filter(outInterval).length

console.log(inIntervalResult, outIntervalResult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually be fine!

You can also do

```
let outIntervalResult = e.length - inIntervalResult
```

If you don’t want to have two functions or filter twice.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find the number of elements in the range and minus this from total number of elements to get the number of elements out of the range.

Irrespective of the logic you use to count the number of elements for in or out of the range, you can return an object (or simply an array) with both counts inside.

```
var array = [1,3,7,10,14,18,20,23,27]
    
function countInOutRange(arr, min, max) {
    let inRange = arr.filter(e => e >= min && e <= max).length
    // Or use a simple for/forEach loop to count 
        
    let outRange = arr.length - inRange
        
    return {inRange, outRange} // or [inRange, outRange]
}
    
console.log(countInOutRange(array, 10, 20))
```

Comment: Make sure you declare `el` properly on that loop with `const` or `let`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
countall = (arr) => {
   countin=0
   countout=0
   arr.forEach(x => (x<20 && x>10)?countin++:countout++)
   return {'in':countin,'out':countout}
}
console.log(countall([1,3,5,7,12,15,17,11,20]))
```

Comment: this is verified working btw

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = [1,3,7,10,14,18,20,23,27]

let [outIntervalResult, inIntervalResult] = 
  array.reduce((r,e)=>(r[+(e >= 10 && e <=20)]++, r), [0,0])

console.log(inIntervalResult, outIntervalResult)
```

Note that `+` coerces a true/false value to 1/0, and so concisely selects the index of the result to increment.

Comment: best answer. clean, concise, & powerful use of javascript syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with a single [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 7, 10, 14, 18, 20, 23, 27];
const minVal = 10;
const maxVal = 20;
let inArr = [];
let outArr = [];

arr.forEach(val => {
    (val >= minVal && val <= maxVal) ? outArr.push(val) : inArr.push(val)
})

console.log(inArr, inArr.length);
console.log(outArr, outArr.length);
```